# Apache Tomcat 8 configuration in windows 7

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to configure Apache Tomcat 8.0.9 on my Windows machine.I set up all the variables whose values are as :-
JAVA_HOME -C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_03
CLASSPATH - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_03
CATALINA_HOME -C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_03

But when i am trying to start tomcat from cmd using command **C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.9\bin\startup.bat** the server is not getting started.

Please suggest me where I am going wrong

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Any messages in catalina log?

Answer (score 0):

The tomcat 8 needs java 7. see the [documentaion](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/setup.html). Install java 7 and try again.